# Put method not working in Google Chrome through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, google-chrome

I have this working fine in Mozilla and IE but for some reason not chrome. In chrome, the error callback executes every time returning an error code of zero. Lots of articles on Stackoverflow keep reiterating how all major browsers support the "PUT" method through AJAX instead of forms. Chrome appears to be the exception.....

**JavaScript**

```
     function works(){alert("working");} // just a success callback

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#crudForm").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"/UtilityDashboard/MeasurementNodes",
            data:parseFormData("crudForm"),
            cache: "false",
            async: "false",
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            type:"put",
            success: works(),
            error:function(xhr){alert(xhr.status + xhr.statusText);} });
    });      

    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <form id="crudForm">
       Name<BR/>
       <input type="text" name="name"/><BR/><BR/>
       Node Id<BR/>
       <input type="text" name="node_id"/><BR/><BR/>
       Type<BR/> 
       <input type="text" name="type"/><BR/><BR/>
       Parent<BR/> 
       <input type="text" name="parent_id"/><BR/><BR/>
       Longitude<BR/> 
       <input type="text" name="longitude"/><BR/><BR/>
       Latitude<BR/>
       <input type="text" name="latitude"/><BR/><BR/>           
       Description<BR/>          
       <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="40">Insert description of measurement node here</textarea><BR/><BR/>           
       <input type="submit" value="Add Node"/>

    </form>
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378894/html5-put-delete-methods-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: Thanks but that article only applies to <form> support for the "put" method. If you see above I'm submitting my data with AJAX. The article you just supplied says this should work in all browsers.

Comment: This works fine for me in Chrome. 21.0.1180.89 distribution.

Comment: How do you know your actually sending the data to the server? For me, I can see the logs since the web server is local, so I know it's not working on my end with Chrome. If you have an alternate mechanism of viewing outgoing data I'm all ears.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy so you get no error message?

Comment: I know I'm sending data to the server because I changed the URL to my controller and checked for a put request. Although, it wouldn't matter. As long as the file is found, it will return successful; however, there will be no data for me to parse. Either way, worked for me.

Comment: Some extension in Chrome may block your request, AdBlock Plus for example.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Cool. Thanks for testing it on your machine. I gotta poke around more then.

Comment: @Eugene Damn. I can reinstall chrome but it's going to be tricky controlling that for other users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So *Eugene* and *OhgodWhy* were correct. Chrome does have support for the "put" method in the XMLHTTPRequest object!

**Solution**

The problem I was experiencing went away when I stopped using the "submit" event to transmit my form data, and instead relied  on the "click" event. This took care of some other issues I was having where after submit chrome would append the form variables to the current URL. This could probably have also been solved by using event.preventDefault.