# $.ajax PUT giving me http status code 0

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Put method not working in Google Chrome through AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489582/put-method-not-working-in-google-chrome-through-ajax)

This is driving me mental:

In page javascript

```
            var ajaxResponse = $.ajax(url, {
                type: "PUT",
                data: video
            });
```

and a web api method

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Video video)
{
    // Never reaches here in Google chrome, unless i call the ajax method 2 times
}
```

This works on the lates IE and Mozilla Firefox, also tried with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) just to be sure.
The GET and POST versions work on all browsers.

On Google Chrome however, i receive http status code 0. I have to call the ajax method 2 times, receive http status code 0 two times and only then the PUT web api controller method gets called. I found no errors in the developer console of Google Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Executing the code with <input type="button" .. solved it for Chrome.